# Event listener is triggered even though I'm using :not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$('.user-card:not(.loaded)').click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).addClass('loaded');
  $(e.target).text('loaded!');
  console.log('this is now loaded');
});

$('.loaded').click(function() {
  alert('already loaded!')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="user-card">
  not loaded
</button>
<button type="button" class="user-card">
  not loaded
</button>
```

I don't want the "loaded!" button to acctivate the `'.user-card:not(.loaded)'`  event listener, yet it does. Why is this?

Comment: Because the selector adds the event before the element has the class. It does not keep on checking.

Comment: At the time you're assigning the event listeners, both buttons are "not loaded". To achieve what you want, you need to use something like `.hasClass('loaded')` *inside* the event listener function: https://jsfiddle.net/0ze5d2j6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event will fire every time because you aren't reassigning click events after each click. You have multiple choices on how to address this. One way I have here is to look at the "loaded" class on the click. If it does not have the class "loaded" then it runs the code. Otherwise the alert fires to let you know the element has already been loaded.

```js
$('.user-card:not(.loaded)').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('loaded')) {
    $(e.target).addClass('loaded');
    $(e.target).text('loaded!');
    console.log('this is now loaded');
  } else {
    alert('already loaded!');
  }
});

$('.loaded').click(function() {
  alert('already loaded!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="user-card">
  not loaded
</button>
<button type="button" class="user-card">
  not loaded
</button>
<button type="button" class="user-card loaded">
  loaded
</button>
```